# How do I give all GitLab users access to all repositories without making the repos public?

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

We're a small team (about 20 people) and I want to give everyone access to all the repositories but without making them public.

Is there a way to make all repositories accessible to every user without making them public? Or so they could at least see/browse all the repos?

So far my approach was to create a team called "Everyone" and just add it to all the repos manually. But I wish this could happen automatically and without everyone appearing as the team.

Any ideas highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: its not possible currently, see http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/3776706-allow-internal-open-public-repositories and http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/4151700-add-a-public-to-gitlab-members-option-in-project

Answer (score 7):

### Add all users to all projects

#### Notes:

■ admin users are added as masters

```
bundle exec rake gitlab:import:all_users_to_all_projects
```

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/raketasks/user_management.md

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [redbook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/) and find the section titled "Enforcing a User-Based ACL System" - it describes how to set up your repository permissions based on just 2 text files per repository - these can be copied between repositories or on Unix/Linux servers could be just 2 files with softlinks in each repository - they you would only have 1 file the users file to edit and not even need to copy it.  You may have to enforce a similar repository structure to each repository but that is often good practice anyway.

The alternatives for a gitlab only solution look like:

1. Adding all your users to a "Browse" group with limited permissions
   and adding that group to all the repositories, (this could be updated
   as necessary using a python script and the [python gitlab api](https://github.com/Itxaka/python-gitlab)),
   ***or***
2. I am *reasonably sure that you can* start gitlab running on a
   specified, possibly non-standard port, make all the repositories
   public but set your network policy up so that only local, or a
   specified range of, IP addresses can connect to that port.  This
   would make it public only within the organisation but as to how to
   do it I would suggest a separate question over on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) as
   it is much more a system admin question than a programming one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But my question was about doing this in [GitLab](http://gitlab.org/) so everybody would be able to see all the repos (in the activity streams and such) without necessarily being part of a repository's team.

I want to make the repositories more open internally but not public. GitLab already provides a way to manage repository permissions manually.

Comment: @MaxKueng I prefer to manage version control systems directly but I have added some possible options for GitLab.  Steve

Comment: yeah, that's about what I am doing now (solution 1). I have a team called "Everyone" that I (currently manually) assign to every project. The problem is that all the users in the "Everyone" team are now visibly assigned to all the projects. But instead what I want is just for everyone to have an overview of all the projects and be able to see the activity stream on the dashboard. I was just hoping that this was a hidden feature that I could just turn on. Thanks for your help.